# Interruptions do not work when a child dialog is interrupted

Tags: c#, botframework

**Using V 4.7.2**

I have the following scenario:

- MainDialog
- HelpDialog (ComponentDialog - Waterfall)
- Dialog A   (ComponentDialog - Waterfall)
- Dialog B   (ComponentDialog - Waterfall)
- Dialog C   (ComponentDialog - Waterfall)

In my **MainDialog** i have an implementation of **OnInterruptDialogAsync** that checks if the user says "**Help**", we will start a **HelpDialog**

In my **OnInterruptDialogAsync** I'm doing the following:

- I have a list of Dialog names that include user **Prompts**
- I check if the **ActiveDialog** is in that list

  - I return  **InterruptionAction**.**Waiting**
- If the ActiveDialog is not in that list --> meaning there is no prompt

  - I return **InterruptionAction**.**Resume**

THE BELOW **WORKS** FINE

- **Dialog A** is running
- **Dialog A** is **prompting** the user a question
- The user types "**Help**" and triggers the Interruption
- **HelpDialog** runs and shows the user a menu then finishes
- RepromptDialogAsync() is triggered and the prompt that the user did not answer to is re-asked again

THE BELOW **DOES NOT WORK**

- **Dialog B** is running
- On the last step of **Dialog B**

  - we end the dialog --> await EndDialogAsync()
  - We begin **Dialog C** --> return await sc.BeginDialogAsync("Dialog C");
- **Dialog C** is running now and **prompting** the user a question
- The user types "**Help**" and triggers the Interruption
- **HelpDialog** runs and shows the user a menu then finishes
- It is expected that the prompt of **Dialog C** to be **Reprompted** **BUT**:

  - **ERROR** : DialogSet.RepromptDialogAsync(): Can't find A dialog with an id of '**Dialog C**'

Has anyone faced this issue before ?

Thank you, 
Marc

Comment: Do you have a "Dialog C" in the HelpDialog DialogSet?

Comment: In my HelpDialog i only have the waterfall steps added - I have just tried to also  AddDialog("DIalog C") which was added to its DialogSet and I still got the same issue

Comment: I assume the problem is down below https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/DialogContext.cs#L463
I'd suggest checking Context.Dialogs and Context.Parent.Dialogs in the debugger

Comment: I suspect the problem is due to which context the dialog is started in. You may be trying to reprompt a dialog from within your "main" context (for me `dc`), but it doesn't exist there because you started it from your waterfall (for me `step`). I ran into this problem when trying to cancel all dialogs from inside a waterfall, and had to use `step.parent.cancelAllDialogs();`. That said, I have a similar interrupt reprompt and do not run into this issue. I simply use `dc.repromptDialog()`, so I'm not sure if this helps you. Also, my main dialog is part of ActivityHandler, not ComponentDialog.

Comment: @billoverton I am using Virtual Assistant Template so my main dialog is indeed part of ActivityHandler, waterfall dialogs are ComponentDialogs, Where are you using repromptDialog() exactly ?

Comment: My interrupt function is in my main bot.js file. I'm doing it by intent, so my code is like this: `if (topIntent === HELP_INTENT & topIntentScore > 0.5) { await dc.context.sendActivity(helpMessage); await dc.repromptDialog(); return true; }`

Comment: @MarcAsmar I'll start doing some testing/debugging, but I believe what might be happening is that DialogState isn't being saved prior to the interruption of "help" being called. If you manually save DialogState prior to acting on the interruption?

Comment: ...that or calling `EndDialog` is removing Dialog C from the dialog stack, which I think is more likely. You should be fine with not calling `EndDialog` and instead only use `return await sc.BeginDialogAsync("Dialog C");`

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT  Once i added "Dialog C" to Dialog B --> AddDialog("Dialog C") The problem i think got solved, Interruption worked as intended. But my chatbot design works dynamically, meaning we get the dialogs that we need to begin from a database, so every dialog has the ability to activate any other dialog and that works fine, we **return await sc.BeginDialogAsync("DialogNameFetchedFromDatabase")** , But that makes it an issue for interruption, in the above scenario it worked cause i manually added the dialog AddDialog()

Comment: What i am doing is, before returning EndDialogAsync on each component dialog, on the last step of the waterfall we check if there are Dialogs that need to be activated from db and activate them --> **return await BeginDialogAsync("DialogNameFetchedFromDatabase")** else i **return await sc.EndDialogAsync();** and that is working great, having the ability to control the bot flow from DB but again this creates an issue in interruptions as it seems i need to actually AddDialog() so interruption works

Comment: @MarcAsmar I think I understand. Sounds like your issue is resolved, then, since you just `AddDialog()`?